# android Edit text with special characters

Tags: android

[image: i have attached the db image where my fields are not stored when i use space or special characters]I have a register form. i need to save the content in db. my data are saved successfully. but when i use  space or some special characters my datas are not stored in db. what should i use to store the special characters and space in db,

```
    if (Name.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Name.setError("Enter your name");
        Name.requestFocus();
    } else if (Dob.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Dob.setError("Enter Date of Birth");
        Dob.requestFocus();
    } else if (Collegeid.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Collegeid.setError("Enter your CollegeID");
        Collegeid.requestFocus();
    } 
 else   {
        String sname = Name.getText().toString();
        String dob = Dob.getText().toString().trim();
        String cid = Collegeid.getText().toString().trim();

}
```

Refer the screenshot above

Comment: What error or problem are you facing actually?

Comment: check what you've got in `string sname` using debugger,edittext will return what exactly it got.problem must be in saving it to DB,that depends on datatype

Comment: Please elaborate. The info provided is too less.

Comment: Most likely you're not escaping query arguments, which also makes them vulnerable to SQL injection. Please post the code you use to make queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `[]` brackets in the `SQLite` statements. It allow to you to add anything what you want.

Comment: For example when i type my name: test means i saves in db if i type name: test. r or test r it does not store in db

Comment: EditText field accept only letters and not white spaces